# Talend - Append two rows from a delimited file

Tags: append, talend, csv

How can I append two rows of a delimited file?

For example, I have:

a | b | c | d

e | f | g | h

and I want:

a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h

This new file may or may not be saved after the transformation.

Comment: So your file only has those 2 rows and you want to change it into 1 row with twice the columns?

Comment: My file has more than 2 rows. I want to join each two rows (1&2, 3&4, ...). Yes, each row will have twice the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any possiblity that you have a join condition or relation between these two rows. Or it is always just two rows, as lets say your file contains 4 rows (how would like to merge them now)
a|b|c
d|e|f
x|y|z
m|g|s

if you have a way to relate these rows, then it will be easier using tmap

Ok the information you have shared in comment helps..

try this
tfileinputdelimited_1 (read all rows from file) -->filter_01 (only 'TX' rows)-->tmap(add sequence start with 1,1) 
so output of tmap will have all columns + sequence_column having value 1, 2, 3..for row 1, row2, row3...and so on..

Similarly have another pipeline 
tfileinputdelimited_2 (read all rows from file) -->filter_02 (only 'RX' rows)-->tmap(add sequence start with 1,1) 
so output of tmap will have all columns + sequence_column having value 1, 2, 3..for row 1, row2, row3...and so on..

Now both these pipeline input them to tMap - and join based on sequence column and select all columns you need from them into single output.

Comment: I want to join rows 1&2, 3&4, ... There is a relation (odd rows have the same content in the 1st field (RX), and even rows have also the same (TX)). I want to join a RX row with the next TX row.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's working! I had never worked with the 'Numeric.sequence', but it was really helpful.